# Passing data between classes is not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

I'm trying to pass NSDictionary between classes. In my AppDelegate I have instance NSDictionary.

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, FBSessionDelegate, FBRequestDelegate> 
{
NSDictionary *contactsFromFacebook;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *contactsFromFacebook;
```

In my AppDelegate.m file I synthesized it as `@synthesize contactsFromFacebook = _contactsFromFacebook;`. Next my step (filling dictionary):

```
-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    _contactsFromFacebook = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:result];
}
```

In my someClass.m file I want to use data from `contactsFromFacebook` dictionary.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSDictionary *someNewDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:appDelegate.contactsFromFacebook];
```

But my `someNewDictionary` is ampty. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked whether you are getting data in FBRequest delegate method?

Comment: Since your property is using _contactsFromFacebook, I suggest getting rid of the contactsFromFacebook variable.  It may not be the problem, but it's unnecessary and a potential source of confusion.

Comment: @mihirios yes. NSLog(@"%@",_contactsFromFacebook); show me filled dictionary.

Comment: @PhillipMills even if I only do `@synthesize contactsFromFacebook;` it does not give any results.

Comment: You don't need the declaration `NSDictionary *contactsFromFacebook;`. When you write `@synthesize contactsFromFacebook = _contactsFromFacebook;` it creates a backing store `NSDictionary *_contactsFromFacebook;` so you are declaring an unused variable `contactsFromFacebook`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In appDelegate write a method:

```
-(NSDictionary*)getSomething { return self.contactsFromFacebook; }
```

And then in other class:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSDictionary *someNewDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[appDelegate getSomething]];
```

And this works fine for me.

Edit:
@Abizern comment i think resolve your issue. He is right.

Comment: Since you mentioned naming conventions: Cocoa methods that start with `get` are expected to have the results returned into the parameters by redirection: e.g. `NSColor`'s `getRed:green:blue:alpha:`. It's described in the [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF)

Answer (score -2):

"@synthesize contactsFromFacebook = _contactsFromFacebook;"

Where is _contactsFromFacebook?

All I see are the following declarations:-

NSDictionary *contactsFromFacebook;

and

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *contactsFromFacebook;

I see no link between the strong property contactsFromFacebook and the variable _contactsFromFacebook you assign to point at the NSDictionary you instantiate

Comment: It's just a naming convention, int's not a real issue.

Comment: @SimpleMan It isn't a naming convention - it creates a backing store using the different name.

Comment: Yes, i know that @synthesize contactsFromFacebook = _somethingDifferent; is perfectly fine, but there is no point for declare this variable some place else. Sorry.